# Laravel event:generate only creates Event and returns error

Tags: php, laravel, events

I'm using Laravel 5.3, I'm following the example here 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#registering-events-and-listeners

I create the following in my EventServiceProvider

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserWasRegistered' => [
        'App\Listeners\AddRoleForRegisteredUser',
    ],
];
```

When I then run

```
php artisan event:generate
```

It's only generating the event and throwing the following error

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]
>     An option with shortcut "q" already exists.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Laravel bug, [already fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16110/files). Simply run `composer update` to update the Laravel framework and all should be ok.

Comment: Thank you! Was bugging me for weeks. Why didn't I think of that.